# single line if statement - Python

Tags: python

I have

```
if board[a][b] == 0:
     board[a][b] = chr(current_char)
```

I want to refactor into one line. Something like the following:

```
board[a][b] = chr(current_char) if board[a][b] == 0
```

It seems that the closest I can come to this is

```
board[a][b] = chr(current_char) if board[a][b] == 0 else board[a][b]
```

But the else clause seems redundant. Is there a stylistically better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is your computer running low on newlines?

Comment: @Barmar good one lol. Have you ever been to Comellas in arlington?

Comment: Yeah, wasn't impressed. Looks better for families who can take advantage of their dinner "messes", I'm single.

Comment: If you want to write your if statement in one line for some strange reason, why didn't you?  Your code remains valid if you hadn't hit return after the colon.

Comment: @DSM I know it works, but is that good style?

Comment: @Apollo none of these answers are good style except the original `if` statement. `python -m this | cat -n`; Lines 3, 5, 9, 10, 15, 19, and 20 apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oldschool Python had a trick for doing the ternary before Python had a ternary operator. Actually, this trick will work in many programming languages. I'm only going to tell you if you promise not to use it.

Promise?

> `[val_if_false, val_if_true][bool(condition)]`

OK, now Python has a ternary, which looks like

```
val_if_true if condition else val_if_false
```

But even that is kinda sloppy. If you really want a one liner, make a function.

```
def val():
    if condition:
        return val_if_true
    else:
        return val_if_false
```

Your *specific* case is a little more specialized, since you want the `else` to be the original value. You could do

```
box[a][b] = box[a][b] or chr(current_char)
```

But again, the `if` statement is just more readable and clear as to the intent.

Answer (score 2):

A more "Pythonic" way of doing this type of thing is:

```
board[a][b] = board[a][b] or chr(current_char)
```

Comment: +1 It's correct, but I don't agree it's Pythonic. Obviousness is an important part of Pythonic-ness. Is it really obvious to the average maintenance programmer that the `or` operator should behave this way when its operands aren't boolean?

Comment: It is definitely not "Pythonic", as mentioned. Look at my example. It would be much clearer what went wrong in the two line version. This example is more C like, though I doubt that a C programmer would suggest it, either.

Comment: We can agree to disagree, but a lot of what is considered "Pythonic" is exploitation of the language's features to obtain succinct expressions for common patterns. For example, Python's "truthiness" is often taken advantage of (including my solution) to reduce extra "noise" (eg. `if len(some_list) != 0...` vs `if some_list...`). To explicitly use variables as they are typed is more of a C thing. Patterns that leverage "duck typing" are something you will see regularly in "Pythonic" programs. Which one is better from a maintenance perspective is another debate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in **Python**:

```
if board[a][b] == 0: board[a][b] = chr(current_char)
```

if all you intend is to put this in one line.

Answer (score -1):

Your two line version is easily the clearest. Stick with it.

```
>>> board[a][b] = board[a][b] or chr(current_char)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What just happened here? If your manager wrote it, you want to find a new manager. If you did, maybe your manager will be looking for a new employee, since the program crashed while you were on vacation.

Comment: I think what happened here still would've happened with the two line version.

Comment: It depends on which line would have caused the error.

Comment: You might be right. But are you sure? That is the point. Where was the error? a, b, board, chr(), current_char?

Comment: I'm sure because I know `chr()` expects an integer. Even if I didn't, I would be surprised to find the issue with `board[a][b]` was a `TypeError` and not a `KeyError`. Can you manufacture a case where the expression `board[a][b]` raises a `TypeError`?

Comment: I can't, but it could raise an IndexError. The point is that localizing the error to a smaller domain is an improvement.